# Where does hive metastore store locks info?

Tags: hive, locking, metastore

I am trying to create indexes on one hive table and getting error:

> FAILED: Error in acquiring locks: Lock acquisition for
>   LockRequest(component:[LockComponent(type:EXCLUSIVE, level:PARTITION,
>   dbname:,
>   tablename:**jobs_indx_jobs_title**,
>   partitionname:year=2016/month=1/sourcecd=BYD),
>   LockComponent(type:SHARED_READ, level:TABLE, dbname:,
>   tablename:jobs), LockComponent(type:SHARED_READ, level:PARTITION,
>   dbname:, tablename:jobs,
>   partitionname:year=2016/month=1/sourcecd=BD)], txnid:0, user:hadoop,
>   hostname:Hortorn-NN-2.b2vheq12ivkfdsjdskdf3nba.dx.internal.cloudapp.net)
>   timed out after 5504043ms.  LockResponse(lockid:58318, state:WAITING)

I want to know in which table hive metastore locks info that it shows while executing "show locks" command?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the Metastore, it's in a ZooKeeper topic...

Just read the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking) and the design decisions back in 2010 for [HIVE-1293](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1293)

Answer (score 0):

If the table is non-transactional, try setting `hive.support.concurrency=false`.